# May one wrap tefillin shel yad over one's wedding ring?

Tags: halacha, tefilin, jewelry, chatzitzah

I have read that one should not have any material between one's tefillin shel yad and one's arm (e.g. bracelets, wristwatches). I always wear a wedding ring on the fourth finger of my left hand. I was taught to wrap the tefillin shel yad strap twice around my third (middle) finger, then once around my fourth (ring) finger. That means that the ring is between the strap and my finger. Is this permissible?

Somewhat related: [Red string on Tefillin arm?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18262/red-string-on-tefillin-arm)

Comment: There is no chatzitzah by the hand

Comment: @sam it's been many years since I learned hilchos tefillin, but I had learned that the fingers (or maybe it was only the middle finger) is the only place other than the bayis where chatzitzah is a problem (and that watches are not problems)

Comment: @Mike, if you can include a source stating that there should be no "material between one's tefillin shel yad and one's arm", that could help others greatly. Thanks for the question!

Comment: Doesn't really seem like a duplicate, @DoubleAA. Besides that it's literally different, there are substantive differences, such as removability of the _chatzitza_.

Comment: Well, it does now at least.

Answer (score -1):

I was told that as you don't really have to wrap *anything* on your hand (it could hang loose from your mid-arm), it's not a problem. And I see plenty of good Jews who wear tefilin over their wedding bands.

Some even wear it over their wristwatches! I'd heard [Rabbi Dovid Gottlieb](http://www.rabbis.org/news/article.cfm?id=100624) (before he made aliyah from Baltimore) discuss this one, indicating there were multiple opinions on it.

Comment: I would make the claim that just because you see others do it, it does not make it correct. If you're able to bring a reliable source, IMHO that would greatly improve your answer.

Comment: I was taught to remove my watch and to this day move my watch to my right arm before putting on tefillin.  I also do not wear my wedding ring when I put on tefillin.