# How does one wrap tefillin with a cast?

Tags: halacha, tefilin, injury

If I had a cast on my tefillin arm, how would I wrap tefillin? Would I only do the shel rosh? Or switch hands? (Assuming this is a full-arm cast.)

Comment: Similar http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17170/759

Comment: I had a cast in the fall (lower half of my lower arm) and my rav told me to put on the tefilla shel had with a brachah and wrap as necessary to hold it in place as the whole elaborate system which we use is derabbanan

Answer (score 2):

Rabbi Eli Mansour [writes](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/displayRead.asp?readID=1961), based on a *machlokes* involving the Rosh and the Rashba:

> Given the difference of opinion in this regard, the Halachic
>   authorities advise a person with a cast on his arm to wear the
>   Tefillin Shel Yad over the cast, but without reciting a Beracha.
>   Instead of reciting the Beracha of “Le’hani’ah Tefillin” over the
>   Tefillin Shel Yad, he should instead recite the Beracha of “Al Misvat
>   Tefillin” over the Tefillin Shel Rosh, having in mind for the Beracha
>   to apply also to the Tefillin Shel Yad.
>
> It should be noted that this entire discussion applies only in a case
>   where the cast cannot be removed and it covers the area where the
>   Tefillin box is worn. Ideally, if possible, one should ask the doctor
>   to apply the cast in a way which allows him to at least wear the
>   Tefillin box on the muscle of the upper arm. If this is not possible,
>   then the Tefillin should be worn over the cast, as discussed.
>
> Summary: If a person has a cast covering the entire arm on which he
>   normally wears Tefillin, and the cast cannot be removed, then he
>   should wear the Tefillin over the cast. In such a case, he recites the
>   Beracha of “Al Misvat Tefillin” over the Tefillin Shel Rosh, and does
>   not recite a Beracha over the Tefillin Shel Yad.

See the linked page for further discussion, and more specific citations.

Comment: Note that this Psak is distinctly Sefardi.

Comment: Hm...this answer got a commentless DV. *I* thought it's a good answer; I have no fight with the Sefardim.

Comment: FWIW, my decidedly Ashkenazi Rav instructed decidedly Ashkenazi me to do this.