# How do you lay tefillin on an injured arm?

Tags: tefilin

My husband injured his left shoulder and will require surgery. How will he lay tefillin?

Comment: relevant: [How does one wrap tefillin with a cast?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/52991/11501)

Comment: see also https://dinonline.org/2010/12/23/tefillin-on-broken-arm/ and https://www.aish.com/atr/Tefillin-on-Top-of-Bandage.html

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Rachel and thanks for this first question. Your question was closed because this site is not a good place for personal questions. Those should be asked to a rabbi well-versed in the relevant laws who will ask questions on context and personal specifics to come to a good answer. This site can't substitute for this. Please don't let this deter you from coming back to learn with us. Also can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?