How to maintain Tefillin
I was doing mivtzaim on Lag B’Omer and there was this one guy that was kind of sweaty. I couldn’t refuse him so I helped him wrap.  The issue is that now, several days later, my tefillin still have sweat stains on the straps and they smell. What can I do to fix this?

Related (though deals with before rather than after) https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/96061/tefillin-care-perspiration

I have updated the link to Sofer Center in the question cited by יהושע ק. As to your current problem, I suggest that you contact your local תפילין sofer for advice.

You can't be the first Chabad member to have this problem. I suggest you look on a Chabad discussion group.
